# filter missing array objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

In my angular 4 application I have the following  array :

```
let sampleArray1 = [
  {
    "name":"Raman",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"20",
        "crtList":[
          {
            "c_code":"087"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"Laxman",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"10"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"raj",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"202"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"raghav",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"30",
        "crtList":[
          {
            "c_code":"97"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In this array some of the objects are missing `crtList`. I need to filter out all such objects and need to have the array which must and should has `crtList`.

So my result sampleArray2 should have the following result :

```
 [
      {
        "name":"Raman",
        "prdList":[
          {
            "p_code":"20",
            "crtList":[
              {
                "c_code":"087"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"raghav",
        "prdList":[
          {
            "p_code":"30",
            "crtList":[
              {
                "c_code":"97"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

}
    ]

How can I achieve this using lodash?

Comment: If you want to be able to do this sort of manipulation on your own, without asking for help, [learn how to here](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Very useful link. I learnt data transformation and functional JS programming myself  from the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, to get sampleArray2, you don't need lodash. A simple `Array.prototype.filter` is enough:

```js
let sampleArray1 = [
  {
    "name":"Raman",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"20",
        "crtList":[
          {
            "c_code":"087"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"Laxman",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"10"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"raj",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"202"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"raghav",
    "prdList":[
      {
        "p_code":"30",
        "crtList":[
          {
            "c_code":"97"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

let result = sampleArray1.filter(function(x) {
  return hasCrtList(x.prdList);
});

function hasCrtList(prdList) {
  for (var i in prdList) {
    if (prdList[i].crtList) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late, but I think it's useful for other developers. You can achieve this easily in just one line of code using Lodash.

`_.differenceWith(fullArrayOfObjects, subsetArrayOfObjects, _.isEqual)`

This function will return missing array of objects that is not in `subsetArrayOfObjects`. Hope it helps.